# Python: Compare the length of different lists and return the longest

Tags: python-2.7, list, compare

I would like to compare 5 lists regarding their length and return the longest list.

I don't have any idea...
Maybe something like this:

```py
a = [1,1,1,1]
b = [1]
c = [1,1,1]
d = [1,1,1,1,1]
e = [1,1,1,1,1]

L = [a,b,c,d,e]

def compare(lists):
    counter = count()
    previous = lists[0]
    group_index = next(counter)
    for value in lists:
        if len(value) >= len(previous):
                ...
```

The result should be 'e'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is py3

```
a = [1,1,1,1]
b = [1]
c = [1,1,1]
d = [1,1,1,1,1]
e = [1,1,1,1,2]
f = [1,1,1,1,1,2]
L = [a,f,b,c,d,e]

def compare(lists):
    previous = lists[0]
    for value in lists:
        if len(value) >= len(previous):
            previous=value
    return previous
Rsss=compare(L)
print(Rsss)
print([ k for k,v in locals().items() if v == Rsss][0])
```

python 2 change items to iteritems

print() to print

Comment: locals().items() save variable pair you can print all of them to see how it works